# Rails: Can't get test to pass on create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make sure that people can't submit a `create` action if they submit an entry with an ID other than their own. For this, I have set up the test as following:

**entries_controller_test.rb**

```
def setup
  @user        = users(:thierry)
  @other_user   = users(:steve)
end

...

test "should redirect create action on entry with id that doesn't belong to you" do
  log_in_as(@user)
  assert_no_difference 'Entry.count' do
    post :create, entry: { content: "Lorem Ipsum"*10, id: @other_user }
  end
end
```

The outcome of the test is that `Entry.count` increases by one, therefore @user can create a post with ID @other_user (is the code correct to create an entry with ID of the other user?)

**entries_controller.rb**: My `create` action currently looks like this.

```
def create
  @entry = @entries.build(entry_params)
  if @entry.save
    flash[:success] = "Your entry has been saved."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "Your entry has not been saved."
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

The instance variable is being passed in to the action by calling `before_action :correct_user` on the action. Here's the `correct_user method`.

```
def correct_user
  @entries = current_user.entries
  redirect_to root_url if @entries.nil?
end
```

By the way, the create action is being called from the index page. I suspect the problem is indeed with authorization since my test can log in the user and create an actual entry.

Can anyone spot an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is only checking whether the current_user has some entries, but there is no validation on the user_id of the entry being submitted to the create action. Moreover, even if the user has no entries, the `@entries` variable will be `[]`, which is not `nil` (so correct_user will never redirect to root). The correct check would have been `@entries.empty?`, but still the object would be created with an incorrect user, as long as the current_user already has some entries belonging to them.

The way I usually go about this is not to permit the user_id parameter (with strong_parameters), and by setting the ownership of new objects to the current_user. If you want to perform the check, your correct_user should look more like this:

```
def correct_user
  unless current_user.id == params[:entry][:user_id]
    flash[:alert] = "Some error message"
    sign_out # This action looks like a hack attempt, thus it's better to destroy the session logging the user out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out on the `correct_user` method – I used @entries.nil? ever since Michael Hartl used it in the Rails tutorial. Changing it does not have an effect on the test though. Hm!

Comment: Oh yes sorry I missed that, the test should be `post :create, entry: { content: "Lorem Ipsum"*10, user_id: @other_user }`. Otherwise that id parameter will simply be ignored.

Comment: No worries! It did not get the test to pass as it does not matter whether you pass `user_id` or `id`. The same thing happens to me to my update action as well – I think I haven't gotten around authorizing post/patch actions quite yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work.

In your entries controller.

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def correct_user
    unless correct_user.id == params[:entry][:user_id]
    else 
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```